# WooCommerce cart discount on second item with coupon code

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to implement a rule to make discounts on products depending on the quantity of products and with a coupon code, taking into account the following points:

With the application of a code the second item has a discount of 40%, the discount must be applied to the item of lesser value, if 4 products are purchased, the discount must be applied to the 2 items of lesser value and so on.

Try this code but it only applies to the second item and doesn't take into account if there are more than 4 items

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_coupon_get_discount_amount', 
'filter_wc_coupon_get_discount_amount', 10, 5 );
   function filter_wc_coupon_get_discount_amount( $discount_amount, 
  $discounting_amount, $cart_item, $single, $coupon ) { 
// Define below your existing coupon code
$coupon_code = 'coupon_code';

// Only for a defined coupon code
if( strtolower( $coupon_code ) !== $coupon->get_code() ) 
    return $discount_amount;

$items_prices = [];
$items_count  = 0;

// Loop through cart items
foreach( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $key => $item ){
    // Get the cart item price (the product price)
    if ( wc_prices_include_tax() ) {
        $price = wc_get_price_including_tax( $item['data'] );
    } else {
        $price = wc_get_price_excluding_tax( $item['data'] );
    }

    if ( $price > 0 ){
        $items_prices[$key] = $price;
        $items_count += $item['quantity'];
    }
}

// Only when there is more than one item in cart
if ( $items_count > 1 ) {
    asort($items_prices);  // Sorting prices from lowest to highest

    $item_keys = array_keys($items_prices);
    $item_key  = reset($item_keys); // Get current cart item key

    // Targeting only the current cart item that has the lowest price
    if ( $cart_item['key'] == $item_key ) {
        return $discount_amount; // return discount
    }
} else {
    return 0;
}
}
```